# Passing a variable to test(window.location) javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using *test(window.location.href)* to show a modal form.

The code is this:

```
var url_res = url.replace(/\//g, "\\/")

if (/url_res/.test(window.location.href)) {
    $('#annotationsModal').modal('show');
}
```

How do I pass *url_res* as a variable and not the string 'url_res'?

Maybe there's another (better) way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, like this:

```
var foo = 'bar'
var regex = new RegExp(foo)
// => /bar/
```

So in your case, you'd do `new RegExp(url_res)`.

And you get:

```
var url_res = url.replace(/\//g, "\\/")
var regex = new RegExp(url_res)

if (regex.test(window.location.href)) {
    $('#annotationsModal').modal('show');
}
```

Check out the [docs for `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on MDN.